# R code to separate movie genres column from a dataset

Tags: r

So I have the IMDB movies dataset which has a column 'genres' which has '|' separated movie genres. ex "Crime|Drama|Horror"

Now each and every row has a different genre combination but I want to separate it out and assign 1 if the movie has that genre and 0 if it doesn't.

I have written this code to get the unique genres which I can make columns of.

```
li = list()
for(x in movie_clean$genres) {
  tokens = tokenize_words(x)
  for(y in tokens)
    li = append(li, y)
}
li = li[!duplicated(li)]
```

How do I now assign 1 and 0 to each separate column from the main genres column?

So I want the final output to be

```
| Adventure | Crime | Drama |

| 1         | 0     | 1     |
```

Edit: each row has different number of genres like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP6Qk.jpg

Comment: There is a function called `separate` but I need some data to put the solution together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options -

1. `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

movie_clean %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(genres, sep = '\\|') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = genres, values_from = genres, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)

#  Crime Drama Horror Action Adventure Fantasy Thriller
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1     1      1      0         0       0        0
#2     0     0      0      1         1       1        0
#3     0     0      0      1         0       0        1
```

Couple of one-liner options

2. `splitstackshape::cSplit_e`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(movie_clean, 'genres', sep = '|', type = 'character', fill = 0)
```

3. `qdapTools::mtabulate`

```
qdapTools::mtabulate(strsplit(movie_clean$genres, '|', fixed = TRUE))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
movie_clean <- data.frame(genres = c('Crime|Drama|Horror', 
                          'Action|Adventure|Fantasy', 'Action|Thriller'))
```

Comment: A wonderful tidyverse solution. Trying to understand its syntax: why is it necessary to create `row`(the variable does not figure further below in the code but without it the code does not work)?

Comment: If you get the data in long format without it (`movie_clean %>% separate_rows(genres, sep = '\\|')`) you'll see that we can't distinguish between the values. We don't know which genre is from which row which becomes problematic when we get data in wide format (using `pivot_wider`). Hence, it is important to have `row` column so that we know the origin of each genre value.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks a lot! But how does `pivot_wider`"know" about `row`since the variable is not anywhere explicitly adressed?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a vector that looks like

```
v <- c("Crime|Drama|Horror", "Apple|Banana|Orange", "Country|Rock|Rap")
```

Then using `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
data.frame(v) %>% separate(v, c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"), sep = "[|]")
```

and get

```
     Col1   Col2   Col3
1   Crime  Drama Horror
2   Apple Banana Orange
3 Country   Rock    Rap
```

Comment: this would work if there were like 3 columns in each row but each row has different number of genres like row1 : "Crime|Drama" row2: "Action" row3: "Adventure|Sci-fi|Biography|War" etc.

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option with `read.table`

```
 read.table(text = v, header = FALSE, sep = "|")
 V1     V2     V3
1   Crime  Drama Horror
2   Apple Banana Orange
3 Country   Rock    Rap
```

#### data

```
v <- c("Crime|Drama|Horror", "Apple|Banana|Orange", "Country|Rock|Rap")
```

Comment: this would work if there were like 3 columns in each row but each row has different number of genres like row1 : "Crime|Drama" row2: "Action" row3: "Adventure|Sci-fi|Biography|War" etc.